# When does a repetitive link in multiple questions become spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I found [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4226705/jhansi-rani) that posted 5 questions in 11 days and 2<sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210952/what-will-happen-when-we-dereference-a-type-cast-pointer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27211884/is-my-analysis-correct-for-this-c-code-snippet)]</sup> of those contained piece of text formatted like this "**www.indiabix.com**". That site seems to be another *Q&A* site.

If he/she posted a full link to question/answer he's asking about, it would be perfectly fine, but this way it seems like an advertisement to me.

When does behavior like this start to be considered spam? Especially when it's another Q&A site which is not well-known (I think links to for example Microsoft forums are just fine).

*Note: I thought that an appropriate action was just to remove bold at this point.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're right not to flag it - I don't think the user is in anyway trying to drive traffic to that site. (If they are they're terrible at it!)

To my mind it looks like they've picked up on some equivalent of project Euler and are working through those. That's not to say this couldn't be part of some wider spammy work, but I'd normally look to find multiple users doing the same.

The other thing that often helps figure out if it's spam or not is a couple of searches:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=www.indiabix.com
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3aindiabix

Typically they'd also post just a couple of times and then abandon the account before moving on to their next account, so you'd see similar users with nearly identical patterns.

Editing looks like exactly the right action from my perspective although I think you could have just removed the domain entirely - it doesn't really matter who they're solving a problem for any more than saying "my high paying client asked", the information we learn about the problem at hand is almost 0.

For what it's worth that user seems to be quite excessively keen on **bold** in general and it wouldn't do any harm to cut back on the usage of that in their posts more widely.

Comment: I guess its hard to quantify *when* behavior like this becomes a spam and you just have to do it case by case. I tried data.stackechange for the first time, but it's seems running condition like `WHERE Body LIKE '%indiabix.com%';` isn't the way of doing things :)

Comment: @Vyktor it's tricky to say for certain without some of the mod tools. Astroturfers are sneaky sometimes. When it gets a bit more blurry a search like the ones I've linked helps a lot though and if you do think it's crossed a line feel free to raise a custom flag with the search and your assessment of the patterns it shows. As it stands though your judgement looks spot on here.